# Encoding categorical data- is there a better way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding

I've been going through a Machine Learning class and of course I've made it more complicated by using a different version of Python and different versions of the libraries it asks me to use.

My course says to use LabelEncoder with OneHotEncoder in order to create dummy variables.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

My console states that categorical_features will be removed in the near future and that I should deploy ColumnTransformer.

After some time on google I've come up with this code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
encod = ColumnTransformer([('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder='passthrough')
x = np.array(encod.fit_transform(x))
x = x.astype(float)
```

This code seems to provide me with the float array I think I need (sorry if I use incorrect terminology. I'm very new to all this) but I'm wondering if I could do better with the same set of tools or if I'll encounter issues in the future.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? Better in performance? In terms of use? Or else?